# How to choose between OpenOffice and LibreOffice in API/SDK

Tags: api, openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno

I'm converting one of our in-house apps to use `OpenOffice/LibreOffice` in addition to `MS Office`.

I was originally worried that it would be difficult to support both `OpenOffice` and `LibreOffice`, but I installed the `LibreOffice` SDK and to my surprise it launched the `Apache OpenOffice` installation (I have both installed).
So far it has been working perfectly, so my worries about `OpenOffice/LibreOffice` compatibility have gone away.

My question is how do you tell the bootstrap method which version to launch?
Is there a way to specify `LibreOffice` instead of `OpenOffice` if both are installed?
I'm developing in `Visual Studio` with `C#/.NET`, but I've gotten pretty good at translating examples from other languages since the OO/LO API examples on the web are so skimpy.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that solution in other languages may be translated/viable:

This is a Java solution.

**Background**

With OOo/LO (OpenOffice.org and LibreOffice respectively) when using Java you need to use juh.jar to establish the connection and this jar must be in the installation folder of OOo/LibreOffice and on the classpath.

This is pretty difficult if you're using maven or installing on a web container... to get around this, this page: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=2520&sid=42b65314c6f727fe42315c9910e443b7 has a download as part of the first post (Feb 10, 2008) and I used the same jar today (Jan 30, 2014) and can verify that it work with LibreOffice 4.1.4 on Ubuntu 13.10. So that should give you further compatibility assurance!

**Solution**

The provided solution as can be seen on that page changes the connection string from:

```
//following assumes juh.jar is in the OOo/LO installation folder and is also on the classpath
com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext xContext = com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.defaultBootstrap_InitialComponentContext();
```

To the following which allows you to have juh.jar as a project resource but also requires bootstrapconnection.jar to be part of the project, because the installation folder is not relative to the juh.jar file it must be explicitly declared, like so:

```
//fully qualified names used to avoid any ambiguity
String oooExeFolder = "/opt/libreoffice4.1/program/";
com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext xContext = ooo.connector.BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(oooExeFolder);
```

The source code is also available in the downloaded jar.

Both OOo/LO start using "soffice".

Having looked over the code (bootstrapconnector.jar) it does not look overly long and should be pretty easy to convert.

**My question is how do you tell the bootstrap method which version to launch?**

- convert the code contained in bootstrapconnector.jar to C# and you should be good to go
- determine the paths to "soffice"
- figure out which one is appropriate to pass in